# Match function in excel

Tags: excel, match

suppose I have this table in excel:

[image]

And I want to use match function to find the value 5:

MATCH(5,B2:B5,0)

How I can return both values in B2 and B4

Comment: return, how?  What is the end desire?

Comment: by appling this MATCH(5,B2:B5,0), it will return 1 only which is the row number of the first (5) value, i want it to return 1 and 3 because there is two (5) in the column B

Comment: okay, do you want two cells, in 1 cell delimited, ...?

Comment: In one cell delimited

Comment: do you have TEXTJOIN?

Comment: clarify please :)

Comment: Do you have the Function TEXTJOIN()?  Basically I am trying to ascertain you version.

Comment: I checked it up and yes I have TEXTJOIN function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN():

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER((ROW($B$2:$B$5)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$5))+1),$B$2:$B$5=5,""))
```

or in Excel 2019

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$5=5,(ROW($B$2:$B$5)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$5))+1),""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

But my guess is that this is only a step to get what you really want, to return the value in column A where it is `5`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5=5,""))
```

2019:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$5=5,$A$2:$A$5,""))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Could we do that with Match function?

Comment: No, the Match is designed to return the first match only.